# Issue defining KneighborsClassifier in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, knn

I am attempting to utilize KNN on the Iris data set as a "Hello World" of Machine Learning.  I am using a Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda and have been clearly documenting each step. A "NameError: name 'knn' is not defined" exception is currently being thrown when I attempt to use `knn.fit(X,Y)`  What am I missing here?  I attempted to test the definition of knn by calling `print(knn)` and I get the following output:

```
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
           weights='uniform')
```

Code below:

```
#import the load_iris dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
#save "bunch" object containing iris dataset and its attributes
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
Y = iris.target

#import class you plan to use
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1)

#Fit the model with data (aka "model training")
knn.fit(X,Y)
```

Comment: what version of python and sklearn are you using?

Comment: this works fine for me, can you try restarting jupyter?

Comment: Please consider posting a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Lines 6 to 29 are unnecessary for your question. Besides that, your code runs flawlessly on my maschine (Python 3.6)

Comment: I am running Python 3.6.3.  It is potentially an issue with my Jupyter Notebook?  I have tried restarting the notebook several times and it does not remedy the issue.  I initially had an issue with creating a new notebook, but once i moved into the anaconda projects file i had no issue creating a new notebook.

Comment: Could you please include the Error Message in your question?

Comment: it's a NameError, which is listed above. "name 'knn' is not defined."  I will add that more clearly to the above

Comment: Did you execute the code exactly the same way you've posted it here? If not, please copy the listing form above and execute it in a single cell.

Comment: @MaxPowers That is copy and pasted aside from the edits you've made

Comment: @MaxPowers This is also code that runs in a Jupyter notebook as also mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162911/discussion-between-maxpowers-and-stormsedge).

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue.
running the following worked for me:

```
model = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
```

ran in:

> Python 3.6.9

Comment: or just:
```from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier```

Answer (score 0):

update your scikit learn modeule.

if you are using jupyter notebook then you can update by running the below code

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```